# Find the accumulated value of an investment fund

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

Find the accumulated value at the end of six years of an investment fund in which \$100
is deposited at the beginning of each quarter for the first three years and \$50 is deposited at the beginning of each quarter for the second three years, if the fund earns 6% convertible monthly.

---

*I need help understanding the solution.*

**Where is the exponent 3 coming from?**
The quarterly interest rate equivalent to 6% convertible monthly is
$$
(1.005)^3 – 1 = 0.015075 
$$

I am not sure now how to find the accumulated value at the end of six years.

Comment: When you ask where the exponent 3 is coming from, are you talking about the following equation?  Note that there are three months in a quarter.

Answer (score 1):

The exponent $3$ comes because there are three months in a quarter.  The $6\%$ per year equates to $0.5\%$ per month.  After three months this has compounded to $1.005^3$

To answer the question, I would make a spreadsheet with a line showing the balance at the end of each quarter, including deposits and interest.  There are formulas that can be used.